# How to get current running flow name inside a flow variable

Tags: lightning

I am creating one salesforce screen sub-flow where I have to display the name of it's immediate parent flow dynamically by using a variable so that when that sub-flow gets executed from any parent flow, it can be able to display the name of it's immediate parent flow.

I've tried using $Flow global variable but got no help.

Please let me know if there is any way to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Off the top of my head I would say just to add an input text variable to the SubFlow, then manually populate it from the calling Flow with its own name.

Comment: That's the real problem. We don't want it to be manually populate it. It has to be some variable which changes for every flow. Is that possible?

Comment: See details in my answer, but you might want to upvote this Idea (which, unfortunately, including my vote, has only 7 votes in 6 years): https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdhu0UAB/flow-add-flow-name-to-the-global-flow-variables

Answer (score 2):

Either you or I (or both) are misunderstanding each other in our comments under your question, so I will try to elaborate here in case I did a not so good job of explaining.

**A**. I can find no easy or even moderately difficult way of automatically or dynamically retrieving even the current Flow's name within itself - much less the name of the calling Flow.

*As I stated in a comment under your question, consider upvoting this Idea: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdhu0UAB/flow-add-flow-name-to-the-global-flow-variables*

**B**. Given **A**, and the fact that you are unlikely to change the name of a "parent" or calling Flow (and even if you did, you could also modify the Flow itself to update what I suggest below), the only way I have found to "get" the name of the current Flow is to manually hard-code it when you are creating the Flow.

##### Suggestion

1. Create an input text variable in the SubFlow which will hold the name (Label or API Name - whatever your use case) of the calling Flow.

   [image] [image]
2. Create a text variable in the calling Flow.

   Manually populate it with the name (API or Label) of that Flow.

   [image] [image]
3. In the calling Flow, call the SubFlow and set the SubFlow input(s) accordingly.

   [image]

##### Proof of Concept

###### Flow

[image]

[image]

###### SubFlow

[image]

[image]

###### Flow Screen Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Flow Name of the current flow is available dynamically.

{!$Flow.CurrentRecord}

On your subflow create a Text Variable, enable it for input.

Then on the parent flow, when you call the subflow, specify {!$Flow.CurrentRecord} in the input field.

[image]

[image]

Cheers
Emma

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. CurrentRecord is just standardized variable name that we can use to store any value, typically the currently being processed record. See https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_pause_recordassoc.htm&type=5